# Why is the -r recursive flag capital in some and lower in others?

Tags: linux, command-line

Some commands use a lower case `r` for their recursive flag while others use a capital letter `R`.

```
cp -r foo/ bar/

chmod -R 777 foobar/
```

Is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`cp` actually accepts both.

From `cp --help`:

```
  -R, -r, --recursive          copy directories recursively
```

For consistency, most shell commands use `-R` as a *recursive* flag, probably because they imitate the behavior of `ls`.

From `ls --help`:

```
  -r, --reverse              reverse order while sorting
  -R, --recursive            list subdirectories recursively
```

Comment: Also, `chmod -r` is already used to mean something other than recursive!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure that there's any specific reason to the inconsistancy other than that programmers can choose to use whatever flags they want.

I don't think there's any form of standard for that so it's hard to expect *everyone* to follow suit.

Comment: The reason would likely be historical. In the larger Unix world which dates all the way back to the 70s, the recursive switches weren't always there, and some commands already had made use of -r as a switch. Because commands are often used within scripts, there's tremendous inertia associated with backwards compatibility, so these  things basically never change - you can add options to a program, but woe be the developer who tries to change long-established functionality.